# GetAsyncKeyState : how to map to a local keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, delphi

I am using delphi (but could be done in any other langage) to develop a simple keylogger using **GetAsyncKeyState**

I can capture the key code, but this is not related to my local keyboard mapping

ex: when I press the "2" key (which on a french keyboard should write the "é", it shows me "2" (VK_2)

My quetsion is : how do I map the GetAsyncKeyState keypressed to the local keyboard  ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use MapVirtualKey function with MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR flag:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Check function MapVirtualKeyEx also, it has locale identifier as input.